# Connecting a minikube pod to a local postgress instance

Tags: postgresql, go, kubernetes

I have a minikube pod running on kubernetes that is supposed to connect to a postgres instance running on docker on my local machine. I'm able to bring up the pod but when I check it's logs I get the following error: failed to connect to `host=host.minikube.internal user=docup database=docup`: dial error (timeout: dial tcp 192.168.67.2:5432: connect: connection timed out)

Here is the .yml code for my minikube pod

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: authentication-service
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: authentication-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: authentication-service
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: authentication-service
        image: "myusername/authentication-service:1.0.1"
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "64Mi"
            cpu: "250m"
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        env:
          - name: DSN
            value: "host.minikube.internal port=5432 user=dbuserpassword=Password dbname=dbname sslmode=disable timezone=UTC connect_timeout=5"
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8081

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: authentication-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: authentication-service
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      name: main-port
      port: 8081
      targetPort: 8081
```

And my postgres.yml file thats running on docker looks like this

```
version: '3.8' #compose file version
#networks:
 # my-network:
    #driver: bridge


services:
  
  postgres:
    image: postgres:alpine
    #container_name: postgres_microservice
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DBUSER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DBPASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DBNAME}
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    #networks:
      #- my-network
    volumes:
      - database_postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  
  
volumes:
  database_postgres:
```

My code is written in Golang and here is the function to establish a db connection

```
func ConnectDB() {
    //Loading environment variables
    //dialect := os.Getenv("DIALECT")
    //host := os.Getenv("DBHOST") - Uncomment when using localhost
    dbPort := os.Getenv("DBPORT")
    user := os.Getenv("DBUSER")
    dbName := os.Getenv("DBNAME")
    password := os.Getenv("DBPASSWORD")

    log.Println("attempting to connect to postgres")

    //Database connection string 
    dbURI := fmt.Sprintf("host=host.minikube.internal user=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable password=%s port=%s",user, dbName, password,dbPort)  //Uncomment when using kubernetes 
    

    //Opening connection to database
    Db, err = gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dbURI), &gorm.Config{Logger: logger.Default.LogMode(logger.Info)})
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("An error occured connecting to db %e", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Successfully connected to db")
    }

    

    Db.AutoMigrate(&models.User{})

}
```

Comment: Are you running on linux? did you enable ip_forward setting? Can you access the postgres db from the host?

Comment: @ChenA. I'm running on Ubuntu on WSL2 on windows. Yes,I can access postgress from the host

Comment: Instead of running some parts in Docker and some in Kubernetes, can you run the database in a Kubernetes StatefulSet?  Then you can directly refer to the Service name as a host name and it's a normal in-cluster call.

Comment: @DavidMaze i'll give it a try. I'm new to the whole devops bit and the tutorial I'm following suggested using docker to simulate a production environment.